# I want to update WooCommerce status for a order with the user name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

[I am able to update status using this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWyx6.png)

In this image highlighted text is username of currently logged in user, when I changed status from dashboard it shows me name, but when I change status using code it won't show any name.

I want username should be display like in this screenshot:

[image: Red boxed note]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not use code in an image! See [ask] and take the [tour]. More links why code as image are bad http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode / https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7571526

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_new_order_note_data', 'modify_added_by');

function modify_added_by($args) {

    $user = get_user_by('id', get_current_user_id());
    $comment_author = $user->display_name;
    $comment_author_email = $user->user_email;
    $args['comment_author'] = $comment_author;
    $args['comment_author_email'] = $comment_author_email;
}
```

Try this code

Comment: This is not working for me, can you guide me little more?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following hooked function to get the shop manager user name in the order note:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_new_order_note_data', 'filter_woocommerce_new_order_note_data', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_new_order_note_data( $args, $args2 ) {
    if( ! $args2['is_customer_note'] && is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can( 'edit_shop_order', $args2['order_id'] ) ){
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', get_current_user_id() );
        $args['comment_author'] = $user->display_name;
        $args['comment_author_email'] = $user->user_email;
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related thread: [Add the Shop Manager username to Woocommerce Admin Order notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734573/add-the-shop-manager-username-to-woocommerce-admin-order-notes/54736592#54736592)

Comment: I am doing this status_update in custom.php which is directly located in my wordpress folder.
so I am trying to update name from there. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @vinayak2910 I don't catch what you are saying… Could you reword and explain that better.