# Complete order based on specific order note in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I want to create a code snippet that completes a Woocommerce order based on a specific order note (“Budbee order status: Delivered”). I am using a hook to do this and I have some code but it doesn’t work. Can anyone please help me? PHP is not my “native” language, so I am not sure if and where I made mistakes.

Two main questions are:

1. Am I using the right hook `woocommerce_new_customer_note`?
2. Is my PHP code correct?

Below is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_customer_note', 'auto_complete_budbee_delivered' );

function auto_complete_budbee_delivered( $order_id, $customer_note ) {
    if ($customer_note == "Budbee order status: Delivered") {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}
```

Thanks a million!!

**UPDATE**

I think I choose the wrong hook (customer note, instead of order note). It might should be:

```
/**
         * Action hook fired after an order note is added.
         *
         * @param int      $order_note_id Order note ID.
         * @param WC_Order $order         Order data.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_order_note_added', $comment_id, $this );

        return $comment_id;
```

The problem here is that you only get the comment_id back, and not the message or the order_id. Any edea how it would work to obtain the order_id and content of the note? This is from the same doc that was shared by @LuicTheAztec. Is `$this` the object containing all the order info?

Comment: Update, it could be that `woocommerce_new_order_note_data` is actually the right hook (based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55263397/trigger-woocommerce-outgoing-email-based-on-an-order-note). Any ideas?

Comment: Code is still not working though, however it seemed like this was the correct hook :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated** *(removed wrong `$` from array key in `$args['customer_note']`)*.

You have not set the function arguments in the correct way for `woocommerce_new_customer_note` *(see it [in the hook source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.6.1/includes/class-wc-order.php#L1724-L1730))*, so try the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_customer_note', 'auto_complete_budbee_delivered' );

function auto_complete_budbee_delivered( $args ) {
    if ( $args['customer_note'] == "Budbee order status: Delivered") {
        $order = wc_get_order( $args['order_id'] );
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}
```

This should better work now.

---

**Edit** *(related to your question edit)*.

Or you may be better use instead `woocommerce_order_note_added` hook this way:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_note_added', 'auto_complete_budbee_delivered', 10, 2 );
    function auto_complete_budbee_delivered( $comment_id, $order ) {
        $comment_obj   = get_comment( $comment_id );
        $customer_note = $comment_obj->comment_content;

        if ( $customer_note == "Budbee order status: Delivered") {
            $order->update_status( 'completed' );
        }
    }
```

This could works if the note content is exactly *"Budbee order status: Delivered"*.

Comment: thank you for the explanation @LoicTheAztec! That indeed seems to be the better syntax, however I am in doubt wether I choose the right hook though. I placed an update in the question.

Comment: @LoicTheAzec, I have your second snippet working now. It didn't work at first but after some debugging and researching, I found out that updating wordpress and woocommerce to the latest version might solve it. It now works flawlessly. A BIG thank you, this save me so much time!!!

Answer (score 0):

For contain word

// order complete note contain strings

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_order_note_added', 'auto_complete_budbee_delivered', 10, 2 );
    function auto_complete_budbee_delivered( $comment_id, $order ) {
        $comment_obj   = get_comment( $comment_id );
        $customer_note = $comment_obj->comment_content;
        
        $word = "Order complete";
        $mystring = $customer_note;
        

        if (strpos($mystring, $word) !== false) {
            $order->update_status( 'completed' );
        }
    }
```