# I want to change status based on order notes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change order status processing to completed if order notes contains "SHIPMENT NUMBER" then change order status based on content.

I tried below code for getting all orders and all order's notes and scan notes content and detect "SHIPMENT NUMBER".

So below code will works when admin add any manual notes and notes contain "SHIPMENT NUMBER" than it will work. But I want to change based on programmatically added notes.

`

```
// Hook into the wp_loaded action to trigger the update when WordPress loads
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_note_added', 'update_order_status_based_on_delhivery_strings', 10, 2);
// Function to update order status based on Delhivery strings
function update_order_status_based_on_delhivery_strings() {
    // Get all processing orders
    $orders = wc_get_orders( array( 'status' => 'processing', 'limit' => -1 ) );

    foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
        // Get order ID
        $order_id = $order->get_id();

        // Get all order notes
        $order_notes = wc_get_order_notes( array(
            'order_id' => $order_id,
            'orderby'  => 'date_created_gmt',
            'type'     => 'internal'
        ));
        foreach ( $order_notes as $note ) {
                $note_content = $note->content;

                // Check if the note contains specific Delhivery strings indicative of an update
                $delhivery_strings_present = (
                    stripos( $note_content, 'SHIPMENT NUMBER :' ) !== false &&
                    stripos( $note_content, 'SHIPPER : Delhivery' ) !== false &&
                    stripos( $note_content, 'TRACKING : https://www.delhivery.com/track/package/' ) !== false
                );

                if ( $delhivery_strings_present ) {
                    // Log a message for debugging purposes
                    error_log( 'Updating order status to completed for Order ID: ' . $order_id );

                    // Update the order status to "completed"
                    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
                    break; // Exit the loop after updating the status for efficiency
                }
        }

    }
}
```

`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64561810/complete-order-based-on-specific-order-note-in-woocommerce

Comment: Thank you for commenting and give me suggestions. I tried same method but not working in my case. My shipping partner is delhivery one. Once Order placed and order shipped by delhivery then my shipping partner will add one note to that order for tracking details. So i want to detect that notes only.

Comment: "based on programmatically added notes" where is this code ? Since you gonna add the note you can update order status from there too ?

Comment: MY shipping partner is adding notes to single order, once order is shipped. So when my Shipping partner add notes to order than i want to detect that notes and want to change order status

Comment: Since you loop all orders will find the first order that have a note 'SHIPMENT NUMBER :' not 'SHIPMENT NUMBER' and stops. You want to target current order only and current note only its faster and cleaner.

Comment: Yes got it Will try your solution and update it

Answer (score 0):

First you dont need to loop all orders since `woocommerce_order_note_added` returns order object. Also you look for `SHIPMENT NUMBER :` not `SHIPMENT NUMBER`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_note_added', 'update_order_status_based_on_delhivery_strings', 10, 2 );
function update_order_status_based_on_delhivery_strings( $note_id, $order ) {
  // Get the note content
  $note = get_comment( $note_id );
  $note_content = $note->comment_content;

  // Check if the note contains 'SHIPMENT NUMBER'
  if ( false !== stripos( $note_content, 'SHIPMENT NUMBER' ) ) {
      // Change the order status to the desired status and add note why status is changed
      $order->update_status( 'completed', __( 'Order status changed based on SHIPMENT NUMBER note.', 'your-text-domain' ) );
  }
}
```